# GNU MAKE - create getoptpp library from my own Makefile or suggest command line options library for c++

Tags: c++, command-line, makefile, gnu

Describe how to compile "getoptpp" as shaded library from my own GNU Makefile and static link it to my program?

**What I do:**

At my program directory I unarchived getoptpp library to subdirectory with the same name. 
than added new target to my Makefile: (README say I used SHARED flag to make. $> make SHARED=n)

```
getoptpp:
     cd getoptpp; $(MAKE) SHARED=n
```

than I added this target to list of requested targets of my program:

```
 myprogram: getoptpp
     g++ **** myprogram
```

but after calling make myprogram - no new .so created at all.
when calling "make getoptpp" - make say 'is up to date'

**ADDED: after suggestion of .PHONY there is an error **

```
cd getoptpp; make SHARED=n
"Makefile", line 15: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 19: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 24: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 45: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 47: Need an operator
make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
*** Error code 1
```

http://code.google.com/p/getoptpp/

OR

Please, suggest pretty nice command line parsing library for my c++ program. That I can simple compile as .o object that link to my program. No Boost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory exists and is not updated, so yes, it is up to date.  Perhaps you want to [declare it as a dependency of `.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: thanks, now there is an error. party makefile is from the box.

Comment: What kind of system is this on?  It looks like your `make` isn't GNU `make`; you may need to invoke `gmake`, especially on a *BSD host.

Comment: yes, now i am at freebsd. thanks, but... obtained that my makefile will not be portable for other *unix systems if I will use gmake at this kind of compilation of this lib? :( not appropriate((

Comment: You don't need to use it for your Makefile, but you *must* use it to make `getoptpp`.